# Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script to send an email. Every time I run it on the formCodes, the script works. On the other hand, after assigning this script, I'm getting this error:

Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient

```
function sendTicket() {
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ms = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var recipient = ms.getRange(1,1).getValue();/**will get the specific email address */

  var message = {/**contents of the email */
    to: recipient,
    subject: "Ticket",
    body: "Hi,\n\nPlease see attached ticket.\n\nThank you!",
    name: "John",
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Ticket Transaction")]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Comment: The obvious question is "What's the contents of ActiveSheet A1?

Comment: a vlookup formula to get the email from the other sheet

Comment: Then I'd guess that it's not working like you think.  Try using Logger.log to determine it's contents or add a conditional to sending that checks to make sure that recipients is not length zero before sending

Answer (score 1):

```
function sendTicket() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ms = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var recipient = ms.getRange(1,1).getValue();/**will get the specific email address */
  var message = {/**contents of the email */
    to: recipient,
    subject: "Ticket",
    body: "Hi,\n\nPlease see attached ticket.\n\nThank you!",
    name: "John",
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Ticket Transaction")]
  }
  if(recipient.length>0) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`Recipient: ${recipient}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I'll be trying the Logger.log to check everything first.